# Tomcat server failure error

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

Hi I am trying to learn Struts ans Tomcat with java ans every tutorial exemple is crashing. I have not found anything yet and I am searching for two days the solution. It says:

```
Infos: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
janv. 08, 2014 5:01:08 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurat
ionProvider info
Infos: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
janv. 08, 2014 5:01:08 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/K:/StefanOprean/sop/java/code/.
metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Events/WEB-INF/lib
/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(Configu
rationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatche
r.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperation
s.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(S
trutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilte
rConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilter
Config.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterCon
fig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:47
75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:
5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:15
59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:15
49)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.Injecte
dObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContain
er - bean - jar:file:/K:/StefanOprean/sop/java/code/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclip
se.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Events/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.
jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
```

and many more.

Some words are changed because the OS is in French (eg: Grave meanse Sever). Please help me!

Shall I post the xml or the jsp files?

Here are the jars that I use
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're either (a) using more plugins than you actually need, e.g., the GXP plugin, or (b) you're missing the plugin's dependencies.

Comment: Ok, and how do I get or remove those?

Comment: Delete them? Please consider using Maven or equivalent for managing dependencies.

Comment: It seems it s having unwanted jars. Follow the link, that runs the struts2 app with required jars. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/

Comment: I am not sure about unwanted jars, because I have put just the ones that are mentioned in the tutorial and they are 7.

Comment: Can specify the jars list that you are using ?

Comment: I have posted a picture with them

Comment: @Muthu I will do the tutorial that you mentioned, but I have made one very similar to it and there were errors too; maybe the same, because the cmd was full and I could see just the last ones.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16883428/573032) answer.

Comment: @Muthu I have done the tutorial you have mentioned and I get errors: `Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(Container
Impl.java:301)`

Comment: Show the whole error that you get.

Comment: @Muthu I have created another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21016585/1360570) to add the errors.