# Tomcat errors when executing tutorial

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I was executing the code from the tuorial from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/ and I am getting the following errors

```
janv. 09, 2014 11:20:02 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/K:/sop/java/code/.
metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsHelloWorld/W
EB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar!/struts-default.xml:64:179
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(Configu
rationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatche
r.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperation
s.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(S
trutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilte
rConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilter
Config.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterCon
fig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:47
75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:
5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:15
59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:15
49)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.Mul
tiPartRequest class:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequ
est - bean - jar:file:/K:/sop/java/code/.metadata/.plugins/org.ecli
pse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsHelloWorld/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.
3.16.jar!/struts-default.xml:64:179
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(X
mlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlC
onfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(Def
aultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(Configu
rationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUpl
oadBase$SizeLimitExceededException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(X
mlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileU
ploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.jav
a:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.jav
a:1547)
    ... 23 more
```

The jars that I use are:

- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- commons-lang3-3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- freemaker-2.3.19.jar
- javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
- ongl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.16.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.16.jar

Can someone tell me what am I wrong? Is the Tomcat server? Is the code?

Another problem is that I was trying more tutorials on the internet and every time I get errors when applying struts2 to the web page. Can someone tell me What am I missing with Tomcat?

P.S. I am using Eclipse kepler, Could it be it th problem?

Comment: Once restart the server and try again? If it's not work once close your IDE and start again

Comment: I did it, it is the same

Comment: Do you configured all jars

Comment: Add Javassist.jar to your LIB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javassist library is missing. You can download it from maven below is the link. This is mentioned in the exception itself :)

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added it and the problem is a little bit different. I have edited the question

Comment: You need commons-io.jar. Please download the same. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: Ok... and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(X
mlConfigurationProvider.java:211) ...` means what?

Comment: you need commons-lang. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: Yes-yes-yes ... I will rewrite the question, sorry about those

Comment: I did not got it. Is it resolved? If this answer helped you please dont forget to mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44874/discussion-between-thedarkside-ofthemoon-and-a-paul)

Comment: Done it, Thanks. the tutorial is not mentioning all the jars

Comment: you also beed http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/ . For your latest error.